# Unix/Linux - File Formating

Tags: text-processing, awk

We have a source file which needs to be formatted into a fixed width file.

Source File Format:

```
Hdr1 
Dtl1.1
Dtl1.2
Dtl1.3
Dtl1.4
Trailer0004
Hdr2
Dtl2.1
Dtl2.2
Dtl2.3
Dtl2.4
Dtl2.5
Trailer0005
.
.
.
.

HdrN
DtlN.1
DtlN.2
DtlN.3
Trailer0003
```

To be converted into:

```
Hdr1 Dtl1.1 Dtl1.2 Dtl1.3 Dtl1.4
Hdr2 Dtl2.1 Dtl2.2 Dtl2.3 Dtl2.4 DTL 2.5
.
.
.
.
HdrN DtlN.1 DtlN.2 DtlN.3 DtlN.4
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed width", I don't see a fixed width in the output example. Where does `DtlN.4` come from? Is this a typo? Is there always a line between chunks like `TrailerXXXX`?

Comment: Are you looking for commands to do that or the algoritm?

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```perl
perl -n -e 'if (m/^Trailer/) {print "\n"} else {chomp; print $_," "}' arun.txt
```

Output:

```
Hdr1 Dtl1.1 Dtl1.2 Dtl1.3 Dtl1.4 
Hdr2 Dtl2.1 Dtl2.2 Dtl2.3 Dtl2.4 Dtl2.5 
HdrN DtlN.1 DtlN.2 DtlN.3
```

Note: the output has a trailing space character on each line.  If you don't want that, get rid of it by piping the output through `sed -e 's/ $//'`.  Or use the following version of the script instead:

```perl
perl -n -e 'if (m/^Trailer/) {
                print join(" ",@line),"\n";
                @line=();
            } else {
                chomp;
                push @line,$_;
            }' arun.txt
```